# Data Expansion in Spark (Scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have tab delimited data that I am reading into an RDD that looks roughly like the following. Let's say there are 12 rows for this example (one for each month in 2010).

Data read into `myRDD`...

```
1/2010    Red    500    Up
2/2010    Blue   300    Left
3/2010    Red    650    Down
4/2010    Green  200    Left
5/2010    Blue   250    Right
6/2010    Blue   300    Up
...       ...    ...    ...
```

I am trying to use this data to mock up a larger RDD by doing something like the following, effectively doubling the size.

```
var biggerRDD = myRDD.union(myRDD)
```

With the union of the RDD on itself I want to increment the date so it appears to span not only the original 2010 dates, but 2011 as well (essentially incrementing the dates in the second half by one year.

I am unsure of how to do this and have been unsuccessful with my attempts.

Comment: So you want to repeat the same *data* but with the year increased by one, right?

Comment: What's the signature of the RDD?

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto yes, exactly.

Comment: @DavidGriffin I'm still a bit new to the technologies. Can you expand on what this means?

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto the RDD is holding each row as an array with a single string... Array("1/2010  Blue  500  Up").  If I split on tabs each row becomes an Array(Array(string, string, ...)), which I have found difficult to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you just need to use a `map` to increase by one each year, check my example below.

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(
  ("1/2010", "Red", 500, "Up"),
  ("2/2010", "Blue", 300, "Left"),
  ("3/2010", "Red", 650, "Down"),
  ("4/2010", "Green", 200, "Left"),
  ("5/2010", "Blue", 250, "Right"),
  ("6/2010", "Blue", 300, "Up")
))

val completeRDD = rdd.union(rdd.map{
  case (date: String, color: String, value: Int, direction: String) => {
    val separator = "/"
    val dt = date.split(separator)
    val newDate = dt(0) + separator + (dt(1).toInt + 1) 
    (newDate, color, value, direction)
  }
})

completeRDD.collect
/*
(1/2010,Red,500,Up)
(2/2010,Blue,300,Left)
(3/2010,Red,650,Down)
(4/2010,Green,200,Left)
(5/2010,Blue,250,Right)
(6/2010,Blue,300,Up)
(1/2011,Red,500,Up)
(2/2011,Blue,300,Left)
(3/2011,Red,650,Down)
(4/2011,Green,200,Left)
(5/2011,Blue,250,Right)
(6/2011,Blue,300,Up)
*/
```

By the way, the result of parsing each observation should be something like this:

```
"1/2010\tBlue\t500\tUp".split("\t")
//res14: Array[String] = Array(1/2010, Blue, 500, Up)
```

And can be committed easily by a `map` is easy to convert into a `Tuple`:

```
val xdd = sc.parallelize(List("1/2010\tBlue\t500\tUp",
                              "2/2010\tRed\t600\tDown"))
val mdd = xdd.map{
  case (str) => {
    val parsed = str.split("\t")
    (parsed.head, parsed(1), parsed(2).toInt, parsed.last)
  }
}

mdd.collect
// res25: Array[(String, String, Int, String)] = Array((1/2010,Blue,500,Up), (2/2010,Red,600,Down))
```